# How to fix physical size of display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.04, xrandr, scaling

### Background

The display, resolution, and connection of my external monitor works flawlessly. However Ubuntu sees the external monitor as smaller than my laptop screen. The monitor is *physically* about twice the width of my laptop screen although the resolution is lower.

Here's how the display dialog looks:
[image: Ubuntu 17.04 display dialog]

I assume the physical size is based on the resolution.

### Problem

This affects how easily and where I can move my mouse from screen to screen. I have to have my mouse in the center of my laptop screen to be able to get to the external monitor display. Even though in reality the monitor has about 6 inches extra on either side of my laptop.

### Additional Details

For reference, the external monitor is an `LG 29UB67` and the resolution is `2560x1080`. I'm running 17.04.

Here's a macbook's rendition of the same dialog connected to the same monitor:

[image: MacOS display dialog]

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 3240, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+
   2048x1536     60.00
   1920x1440     60.00
   1856x1392     60.01
   1792x1344     60.01
   1920x1200     59.95
   1920x1080     59.93
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1152x864      60.00
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   960x600       60.00
   960x540       59.99
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   576x432       60.06
   512x384       60.00
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   320x240       60.05
DP-1 connected 2560x1080+746+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   2560x1080     60.00*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1920x1080i    60.00    59.94
   1680x1050     59.95
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```